# For TestCase how to set a Property?

Tags: nunit-3.0

In NUnit I can do the following, and afterwards retrieve the ID from TestContext

```
[Test]
[Property("ID", "HelloWorld")]
[Category("ABC")]

// TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Properties.Get("ID").ToString() 
// --> HelloWorld
```

What doesn't seem to work is the below (It returns null when you look for ID in TestContext)

```
[Category("ABCD")]
[TestCase("AZ", 1),Property("ID","a")]
```

Same for

```
[Category("ABCD")]
[TestCase("AZ", 1)]
[Property("ID","a")]
```

Is this even possible, or am I so thick I can't see the right answer?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that there is an alternative formulation. It's one which I had never seen used before. I found the description here https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/TestCaseData

```
[Test
public class ObjectPattern
{
    [TestCaseSource(typeof(ADataClass), "TestCases")]
    public int DivideTest(int n, int d)
    {
            ;
    }
}

public class ADataClass
{
    public static IEnumerable TestCases
    {
        get
        {
            yield return new TestCaseData(12, 3).setProperty("ID",4);
            yield return new TestCaseData(12, 2).setProperty("ID",4);
        }
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

interesting question. I made a test project and you're right. It doesn't work.
Research on NUnits GitHub and there is an open bug, which is present around three years: https://github.com/nunit/nunit/issues/1358

So current implementation of NUnit doesn't let to apply Property attribute to TestCase with success.